# How can I print two small files on the same page with a2ps?

Tags: linux, command-line, printing

I'm using Ubuntu Linux 12.0.4.1 LTS and I like the auto-formatting that a2ps does. I just want to print several small files using as few pages as possible.
Example: `a2ps file1.c file2.c file3.c file4.c`
These will print out (depending on printer settings) on their four separate pages, or on opposite sides of two two-sided pages, like this:

--- page 1---

side 1: `file1.c text` `blank column`

side 2: `file2.c text` `blank column`

--- page 2 ---

side 1: `file3.c text` `blank column`

side 2: `file4.c text` `blank column`

I want to have them all on one sheet of paper:

--- page 1 ---

side 1: `file1.c text` `file2.c text`

side 2: `file3.c text` `file4.c text`

Comment: See http://www.math.grinnell.edu/mathlan/printing-with-a2ps.xhtml

Comment: `a2ps -2 --sides=duplex` almost does what I am looking for, but it still leaves each file on its own page. Is there a way to fill the missing column with the next file if the current file isn't long enough to extend into it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by generating eps files and including them in a latex file as figures. Latex places them on the same page if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-A` flag of `a2ps`:

> ### -- Option: `-A` *MODE*
>
> ### -- Option: `--file-align=`*MODE*
>
> Align separate files according to MODE.  This option allows the printing of more than one file on the same page.  MODE can be any one of:
>
> - `virtual`: Each file starts on the next available virtual page (i.e.,  leave no empty virtuals).
> - `rank`: Each file starts at the beginning of the next row or column depending on the `--major` setting.
> - `page`: Each file starts on a new page.
> - `sheet`: Each file starts on a new sheet.  In Simplex mode, this is the same as `page`; in Duplex mode, files always start on a front side.
> - an integer *NUM*: Each file starts on a page which is a multiple of *NUM* plus 1. For instance, for `2`, the files must start on odd pages.

For example:

```
a2ps -A virtual -- file1.c file2.c
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by describing what the ```-A``` option does, and linking to a reference.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Answer (score 0):

`a2ps --rows 1 --columns 2 yourFile1 yourFile2`